# Differences in SNMP version commands

Tags: snmp

I am working on a project about SNMP.

I know that between SNMPv1 and SNMPv2, SNMPv2 has GetBulk and Inform commands in addition. I would like to know that for the commands that are supported in the three versions like Get GetNext Set etc.., is there a difference in terms of compatibility or is there any difference that I should know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SNMPv1 is missing GetBulk and the TRAP2 and INFORM commands (and REPORT, but you probably don't ever need to know that it exists).  Other than that, SNMPv2c is a minor change to SNMPv1 that only adds these three commands.  SNMPv3 uses the SNMPv2 PDU format so the command list is identical.  SNMPv3 only wraps security and other processing around the SNMPv2 PDU set.

Answer (score 0):

- REPORT is almost v3 only.
- GET BULK, TRAP v2 and INFORM are v2c/v3 only.
- TRAP v1 is almost v1 only.

Other commands are available in all three versions.

Note that the message format is almost identical in v1 and v2c, while v3 uses a more complex format.

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion1SNMPv1MessageFormat-3.htm

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion2SNMPv2MessageFormats.htm

http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_SNMPVersion3SNMPv3MessageFormat.htm

The SNMP RFC documents listed in this Wikipedia page provide you more details on them,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol

There might be other issues during your exploration, and once you hit anything, you can post here again as a new question.